# Base directory for browscap path

Tags: php

In PHP.ini there is a line for adding a browser capability file:

```
browscap = extra/browscap.ini
```

Which directory is this path relative to?

Answer (score 0):

It indicates;

```
// in windows (my pc):
D:\LAMP\php5.3.10\extras\browscap.ini
// in ubuntu
/usr/share/php5/extras/browscap.ini (or somewhere like this where php is located)
```

Comment: Is there any way to specify a general root directory for PHP, so that you don't have to write full paths for every directory setting in php.ini?

Comment: Afak, you don't need full path indication in `php.ini`, it takes php.ini current path to indicate full path for extensions and extras. But full path of file inclusions in applications could be set by `set_include_path`. So can't do this (in php.ini); ie. `line:1 -> PATH = usr/share/php5 ... line: XXX -> browscap = PATH /extras/browscap.ini`. See more details: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php